# Starting Function When Check/Uncheck Checkbox JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show an image when the checkbox is checked and show a text when it is unchecked.
When I check the checkbox I get the image but when I uncheck it the text doesn't show.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkword" onchange="tran()">
<label for="checkword" class="word" id="word"></label>
```

```
let wordel = document.getElementById('word');
wordel.innerHTML = "A";
function tran() {
    if(wordel.checked != false){
        wordel.innerHTML = "";
        wordel.innerHTML = '<img src="001.gif">';
        wordel.style.padding = "0px";
        wordel.style.background = "none";
    } else {
        wordel.innerHTML = "A";
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `getElementById('word')` to `getElementById('checkword')`. The object with word as the id is a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're checking the wrong element is checked.

You are checking that wordel is checked, but that's the label element.

You want to check:

```
document.getElementById("checkword").checked
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS alone

```css
/*Hide the span when checkbox checked*/
#checkword:checked + label>span {display:none;}
/*Hide the image when checkbox unchecked*/
#checkword:not(:checked) + label>img {display:none;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkword">
<label for="checkword" class="word" id="word"><span>Word</span><image src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></label>
```

However this relies on the label being the direct following sibling of the checkbox, which isn't always possible. In those cases, leave your HTML in HTML and a combination of CSS and JavaScript to show an hide things.

```js
/*Add a click event listener*/
document.getElementById("checkword").addEventListener("click", function(){
  //Toggle the active class based on the checked status of the clicked checkbox
  document.getElementById("word").classList.toggle("active", this.checked);  
})
```

```css
/*Hide the span when checkbox checked*/
label.active>span {display:none;}
/*Hide the image when checkbox unchecked*/
label:not(.active)>img {display:none;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkword">
<label for="checkword" class="word" id="word"><span>Word</span><image src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"></label>
```

Comment: Thank you, nice trick. I wish you the best.